# php simple xml element question/bug

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml

I have some xml, lets say `<names number="12"></names>`

When I run the following:

```
$simpleXMLElement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
pr($simpleXMLElement);
```

I get the following:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [number] => 12
        )

    [0] => 

)
```

It throws in that 0 entry. This is weird. I don't know what it's supposed to represent. If I do this instead:

```
<names number="12"><name first="oliver" /></names>
```

I get the following output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [number] => 12
        )

    [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [first] => oliver
                )

        )

)
```

This is as expected (for me at least). Any thoughts/direction?

Answer (score 0):

First: if you don't correctly format your post, the XML will not be displayed. Indent any code with at least 4 spaces.

Secondly, do not expect `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to give you an exact representation of a `SimpleXMLElement` because SimpleXML uses lots of magic, so children and attributes won't necessarily show up in the output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be just SimpleXML doing a quick-and-dirty job of parsing the element: Since you have `<names></names>`, it adds an array inside the element, as expecting elements within it, and when it doesn't find any elements inside the `names` tags, it leaves an empty array, with the key `0`, since it doesn't know what name to give it.

A short tag (`<names />`) shouldn't generate the empty content. (As weird as that sounds.)